# Stubbing methods of injected beans in another bean's constructors

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I test a Spring bean using constructor injection. The injected bean is defined as `@MockBean` in the testcase and also the appropriate stub is defined: when a certain method of the mocked bean is called, then it should return a mocked object.

When I start the testcase I get a `NullPointerException`, because the stubbing does not work – the method returns always `null`.

Here is the constructor of the object to test:

```
@Autowired
public MyBeanToTest(msTemplate jmsTemplate) throws JMSException {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    this.cf = this.jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory(); // cf is always null
    cf.createSession(); // NPE
}
```

Here is the testcase:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTestClass {
    @Autowired
    MyBeanToTest myBeanToTest;

    @MockBean
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Mock
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testSomething()  {
        ...
        when( jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory() ).thenReturn( connectionFactory );
        ...
    }
}
```

I assume the defined stubbing is not active yet when the constructor is called.
Any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Obtaining the `ConnectionFactory` from the `JmsTemplate` and operate on it in the constructor is actually a bad idea. You shouldn't get the `ConnectionFactory` like that, just inject it. Looks like the construct in that class is flawed to begin with (the fact that it is hard(er) to tests kind of points into that direction as well),

Comment: Anyhow the line `cf.createSession()` will return NPE, because `cf` is a mock (it's the `connectionFactory` from the test class), and you didn't define to it what to do in case of calling the `createSession()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Your best bet is to create the bean ‘by hand’ instead of letting Spring call the constructor all by itself. To this end, add a `@Configuration` class to your test that has the corresponping `@Bean` method.

---

Untested example:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTestClass {

    @Configuration
    static class MyTestClassConfiguration {
        @Bean
        MyBeanToTest myBeanToTest(jmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
            // Too bad that this is not within the test…
            when(jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory())
                    .thenReturn(connectionFactory);
            …
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use static stub so it would exist and be configured prior creation of the context.

Another, cleaner approach, is to NOT to call anything in the constructor, but to create your session with `cf.createSession();` on demand (it still can be singleton).

Yet another approach is to NOT to use @MockBean at all, and just create `GegugProcessingSoapServices` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to mock but to stub the `JmsTemplate` bean.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTestClass {
    @Autowired
    MyBeanToTest myBeanToTest;

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Mock
    private static ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {
        @Bean
        public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
            return new JmsTemplate() {
                public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
                    return connectionFactory;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething()  {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`@AutoWired` is not intended for use for class under test. It won't take the bean into the constructor .

The solution can be possible to use Mockito `@InjectMock`, or to create the class yourself and use a mock in the constructor (this is generally a good practice):

`MyBeanToTest myBeanToTest = new MyBeanToTest(connectionFactory)`

Comment: `@MockBean` does just that, it replaces the actual bean with a mocked instance. Messing around with mocking instead of using this will only complicate things.

Comment: My humble opinion is that "new" with the mock, is much simpler and readable regarding the creation of configurations. Regarding the `@MockBean` you're right.